# Update statements containing multiple sets

Tags: sql

I'm a bit confused on why I'm seeing a difference between the two statements. I'm trying to simply increment an INT column by 1, so setting values to 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.:

QUERY #1 produces the desired result:

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 0
UPDATE #jc_TEMP 
SET num = @a, @a=@a+1
```

QUERY #2 sets all rows to 0:

```
DECLARE @a int
SET @a = 0
UPDATE #jc_TEMP 
SET num = @a
SET @a=@a+1
```

Obviously I'm missing something here, but to the naked eye they appear to be the same. Does the local variable rollback somehow in the 2nd query?

Comment: Any specific database?

Comment: Your second query doesn't have a `WHERE` clause on it, so it will set every record to 0.  The first one you're also incrementing the `@a` variable as it updates.

Comment: @Siyual - Is there any other way to rewrite the 1st query without using cursors? Also, why is the lack of a where clause not a problem with query #1? Thanks!

Comment: @parrotsnest Why do you need to rewrite the first query?  You said it produces the desired result!

Comment: @DStanley I don't, just curious for learning purposes. :)

Comment: @parrotsnest Some databases have mechanisms to product a "row number" but the syntax is different across providers - there's not a "standard" SQL syntax for it.

Comment: This is something that bothers me, but why does the first row get updated to 1 instead of 0 here? Does the SET order not go from left to right? I would assume the first row would be updated with the @a value of 0, then update that variable to be +1, and update the next row to 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the second "UPDATE" is actually *two separate statements*:

```
1 - DECLARE @a int 
2 - SET @a = 0 
3 - UPDATE #jc_TEMP 
      SET num = @a 

4 - SET @a=@a+1
```

The `UPDATE` sets all rows to the value of `@a` (which is 0), then the *next* statement increments `@a`.

Your first `UPDATE` :

```
1 - DECLARE @a int
2 - SET @a = 0
3 - UPDATE #jc_TEMP 
      SET num = @a,
          @a=@a+1
```

increments the value of `@a` *for each row*, so you see the increments in the data.

Comment: This is something that bothers me, but why does the first row get updated to 1 instead of 0 here? Does the SET order not go from left to right? I would assume the first row would be updated with the @a value of 0, then update that variable to be +1, and update the next row to 1.

Comment: I would too, but that may be an implementation detail - what type of database are you working with?  SQL Server?  MySQL? Oracle?

Comment: I'm using SQL Server.